# NSProgressIndicator not working inside function with callback

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I have an NSProgressIndicator (progress bar) that seems to work perfectly when inside a delegate method like such:

```
func restClient(client: DBRestClient!, uploadProgress progress: CGFloat, forFile destPath: String!, from srcPath: String!) {
        if progress == 1.0 {
            progressBar.hidden = true
            generalAlert("Uploaded", text: "Your File has been saved to your computer and uploaded under: \(destPath)")
        } else {
            progressBar.hidden = false
            print(progress) // e.g 0.010213
            progressBar.doubleValue = Double(progress)*100
        }
    }
```

However, when placed inside a function with a callback, I don't seem to be able to modify it in any way (accepts neither my isHidden = false call, not a doubleValue update).

```
CloudConvert.convert([
            "inputformat": "gif",
            "outputformat" : "mov",
            "input" : "upload",
            "file": name],

            progressHandler: { (step, percent, message) -> Void in
                print(percentage!) //e.g 10.31451. Called every second
                self.progressBar.hidden = false //Doesn't Work
                self.progressBar.doubleValue = Double(percentage!) //Doesn't Work
            },
            completionHandler: { (path, error) -> Void in
                if(error != nil) {
                    self.progressBar.hidden = true
                    self.generalAlert("ERROR", text: "Your file could not be uploaded")
                } else {
                    self.progressBar.hidden = true
                    self.generalAlert("MOV Uploaded", text: "Your MOV has been saved to your computer and uploaded")
                }
        })
```

Can anybody provide an idea of why this might be?

Comment: are you sure the callback is on the main thread?

Comment: I wasn't! That was the answer! Would you put it as an answer, and not a comment so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Your completion handler will be running everything in a background thread, and you need to make UI calls on the main thread.

Wrap up your progress bar calls in a dispatch to the main queue like this

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.progressBar.hidden = false //Should now Work
        self.progressBar.doubleValue = Double(percentage!) //Should now Work
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. If you found the question to be relevant, please upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your UI code in a DispatchQueue.main.async block.
UI operations Off of the main thread presents delays.